# it may seem like a silly question but it's confusing to me regarding the (++) and it's position in php

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, break

### this code prints to 10##

```
<?php

$value=1;

do{

echo $value."<hr>";

if ($value>=10) {

break;

}

$value++;



}while (true);

?>
```

### But this code prints to 9

```
<?php

$value=1;

do{

echo $value."<hr>";

$value++;



if ($value>=10) {

break;

}

}while (true);

?>
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation for [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)? Anything specific from there you don't understand?

Comment: This question really seems to be about logical flow of your code. Congratulations - you've successfully discovered that making changes to your order of operations materially affects your outcomes! You might strongly consider brushing up on your PHP syntax and understanding of general logic flows if this is what is in fact tripping you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- print value (prints 1)
- ++ (adds 1 to $value)
- check if value is > or = to 10 and break if it is

that is why you loop never gets to printing 10 since it breaks when the value is equal to 10

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you'll print 10, realize it's 10 (if statement), then break. In the second case you'll print the 9, increment it to 10, then realize it's 10 and break, thus never printing the 10.

So if you want the second one to print 10 as well you need to more the echo to after the ++, thus ensuring that the value is incremented before the break is reached.